# Coinmarketcap widget is not responding to request

Tags: node.js, discord.js, price, request-promise, coinmarketcap

I was using this code to get data of the currency like price, market cap etc...
I'm preparing new bot and the request is not working due api error...

Code:

```
'use strict';

const rp = require('request-promise');
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://3rdparty-apis.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/widget?id=3501&convert=BTC,ETH,USD',
  headers: {
  json: true,
  gzip: true
  }
};

rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
  const answer = JSON.parse(response)
  console.log('API Call response:', answer["data"]["3501"]["quote"]);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('API Call error:', err.message);
});
```

Error:
`API Call error: 403 - "error code: 1020"`

Any ideas what is wrong?
**https://3rdparty-apis.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/widget?id=3501&convert=BTC,ETH,USD**

It works perfectly fine and i can see all the data when im puttin link inside web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your user agent like:

```js
'use strict';

const rp = require('request-promise');
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://3rdparty-apis.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/widget?id=3501&convert=BTC,ETH,USD',
  headers: {
  json: true,
  gzip: true,
  'User-Agent': 'Discordbot/2.0'
  }
};
```